# What is a normal distribution with 'common variance'?

Tags: distributions, probability, normal-distribution

[*Data Augmentation Approach in Bayesian Modelling of Presence-only Data* (Divino *et al.*)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1878029611001356) states that the data ware sampled from a normal distribution with mean 2.0 and a common variance (section 3). Does anyone know the value of a 'common variance'? Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid the question does not have a 'standard' answer as I suspect that the authors are using a term that may be domain/context specific. What is this paper? A link/reference may help in answering your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the link to the paper and edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table 2 lists three values for $\sigma_x$. I believe that they performed a simulation study by generating the covariate $x$ from a mixture normal distribution with  $\sigma_x$ set to either 0.5 or 1 or 2. The term common variance in this context refers to the fact that the variance of the components of the mixture are identical.